# Check type of generic class without respecting generic type constraint

Tags: swift, generics

I have the following structure:

**class `A`**

```
class A<T: SomeInterface> : C {

}
```

**class `B`**

```
class B : SomeInterface {
    func someFunc(param: C){
        // check if param is of class A with `self.dynamicType` generic type
        if let typedC = param as? A<self.dynamicType> { // does not work

        }
    }
}
```

I would like to check if `param` has a class of type `B` as a generic constraint. Is there a way to specify a wildcard generic type ? It is not of importance whether the generic constraint in fact is of type `B` or not, but this wouldn't be possible either:

```
class B : SomeInterface {
    func someFunc(param: C){
        // check if param is of type A 
        if let typedC = param as? A { // don't check generic constraint type

        }
    }
}
```

or (in case there is a wildcard):

```
class B : SomeInterface {
    func someFunc(param: C){
        // check if param is of type A with wildcard (Is there such a thing as a wildcard?)
        if let typedC = param as? A<?> { // don't require specific generic type, just enter if param is of type A

        }
    }
}
```

## EDIT - Playground sample

```
import UIKit

protocol SomeInterface{
  func someFunc(param: C)
}

class C {


}

class A<T: SomeInterface> : C{

}

class B : SomeInterface {

  func someFunc(param: C) {

    // A is a subclass of C, but I want the typed generic subclass
    if let typed = param as? A<self.dynamicType> {

    }

  }

}

let b = B()
let a = A<B>()
b.someFunc(a)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to express how complicated the world gets once you start allowing non-final subclasses. If you can possibly make these final classes or protocols, many little sharp edges will go away.

What you say you want and the code you're writing don't really line up (which is *very* common when dealing with subclasses). So it matters what you really want.

> I would like to check if param has a class of type B as a generic constraint.

Sure. That's easy.

```
class B : SomeInterface {
    func someFunc(param: C) {
        if let typed = param as? A<B> {
            print(typed)
        } else {
            print("NO")
        }
    }
}
```

This will work anytime we get an `A<B>`. It will not work if we receive `A<SubClassOfB>`, even if that's passed to `SubclassOfB.someFunc()`. (See what I meant about it being subtle?)

From your code, you seem to actually want "if I'm passed `A<Self>`" where "Self" means "exactly my class, not a superclass or subclass." The only way I've ever seen that done is with a protocol extension:

```
extension SomeInterface {
    func someFunc(param: C) {
        if let typed = param as? A<Self> {
            print(typed)
        } else {
            print("NO")
        }
    }
}
```

This allows `Self` to be replaced with "my class." But note that this means `someFunc(A<MySubclass>)` won't work. `A<Self>` is not the same thing as `A<Subclass>`. Note that you can add a `where` clause to the extension to limit its scope:

```
extension SomeInterface where Self: B { ... }
```

If you mean "`T` is either `Self` or some subclass of `Self`", maybe it's possible, but in my experience it gets more and more tricky and fragile. You can't make generic types covariant on their parameters in Swift, so `A<Subclass>` is not itself a subtype of `A<Superclass>` (that's a much trickier problem than it sounds like, and you wouldn't always want it to be true). This is the kind of crazy corner case that goes away if you'll just mark `B` as final. Then most of the rat's nest goes away.

Comment: Huh... I get the idea and extending the `UIKit` protocol (The function is from a `UIKit` delegate) is not an option either (It's probably not possible to call the super function from the extension). Guess I'll have to refactor my code :(. Thanks for taking the time though.

Comment: It's not possible to call "super" within an extension, but you can create a helper method in the extension and call that. But even better in this kind of case is often to just create a helper object, and call it from the delegate rather than making the helper object itself the delegate. That way your helper doesn't have to be a subclass. Good luck.

Comment: Good point, but not sure if that will cut it for me. Back to the drawing board!

Answer (score 1):

When you define:

```
class A<T: SomeInterface>{

}
```

you are not defining a class, and so a type, but a generic type A, that *must* be instantiated to become some type.

So, you cannot define inside another class a function in this way:

```
func someFunc(paramA: A)
```

This will give always a type error. Instead you should define:

```
func someFunc(paramA: A<SomeTypeSubtypeOfSomeInterface>)
```

For instance, since you have defined `B` as subtype of `SomeInterface`, you could define:

```
func someFunc(paramA: A<B>)
```

Comment: in particular `func someFunc(paramA: A<B>)`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, but I think I could not properly project my use case onto the question above. Apologies for that. `A` is actually a subclass of a non-generic class `C`. The function actually gets passed in an instance of `C` and I want to check whether it's actually the generic subclass `A` (which has a generic constraint). Does that make sense ?

Comment: Is A both a subclass of C and generic? How it is defined?

Comment: The function is a delegate function in UIKit, I don't really want to wrap that, so I have no control over the passed in parameter. So I get an instance of `C` as a parameter, but in reality it is my custom subclass that takes a generic parameter, so I would like to work with that instead by "casting" it.

Comment: `A` is defined like this: `class A<T: SomeInterface> : C {}`

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to reproduce your example, but I can not do that. Could you please update your question?

Comment: Sure, I will set up a playground and post the code.

Comment: I'm looking at your example, now. So in the guarded if you want to check if the parameter is of type B ?